# What type of regexp would I need to extract image url from markdown?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following

```
Some post content here
![Habits Are Hard to Build and Break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tToTx.jpg)

Yad ayaday dyaya 

 * Hi
 * There
```

How could I extract the first image in markdown? E.g I basically want to parse it then save the first image to a variable like `extractedImage` "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tToTx.jpg"

```
extractImageFromMarkdown(text) {
  // somehow parse text to grab first image_url
  return extractedImageUrl;
}
```

Comment: The format for images is pretty simple, it's `![description](url)`.  You know what characters come before/after the url.

Comment: When making regexes, I like using a site like: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
text.match(/!\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)/)[1]
```

This assumes that you can't have any escaped brackets though, like `![\]]` which is probably a safe assumption.  This will also get only the *first* image as requested.